# How to get checked items from a custom adapter?

Tags: android

The listview I used has custom xml and adapter. I want to get the checked items from this listview from anywhere. My xml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Item" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Subtitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My adapter is here:

```
private final List<Model> list;
private final List<Model> list2;
private final Activity context;
boolean checkAll_flag = false;
boolean checkItem_flag = false;

public Adapter(Activity context, List<Model> list, List<Model> list2) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.list2 = list2;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected TextView text2;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                list.get(getPosition).sec(buttonView.isChecked());
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.text, viewHolder.text);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.text2, viewHolder.text2);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.cb, viewHolder.checkbox);
        } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position);

    viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).isimGetir());
    viewHolder.text2.setText(list2.get(position).isimGetir());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).secilimi());

    return convertView;
}
```

My aim is that getting checked items from a method placed in Main activity. However I cannot catch the values of checkboxes because of they're custom.

Answer (score 0):

An approach you might use is to keep track of the checked items in the main activity by calling back to the main activity via intent or public method to maintain a list of them.  Add and remove as the checked condition changes.  You can fire off the intent or method whenever the checked value changes or on load in the adapter.